# Error al instalar Android studio en Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenos dias,

Recientemente he instalado Android Studio en Ubuntu y luego de instalarse los jdk me arroja este error.

> "Error:Unable to get the CMake version located at:
>   /Android/Sdk/cmake/bin"

Me pueden ayudar con alguna solucion?

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que instalar el "CMake 3.7" o superior. Lo puedes descargar en: https://cmake.org/download/

Luego tienes que editar el archivo "local.properties" que está localizado en tu proyecto. Y añadir la direccion del directorio que contiene al archivo "cmake".

```
cmake.dir="/home/Downloads/cmake-3.9.5/"
```

En mi caso, el directorio se encuentra en: "/home/Downloads/cmake-3.9.5/". Para el caso tuyo, tendrás que buscarlo. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fuente bibliográfica: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: Y no olvidar que tambien hay que instalar el "ninja-build" en  Ubuntu: `sudo apt install ninja-build`